# Textbox's text is not selected when launching the exe directly

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a simple textbox with a text saying "Username".

- When I launch the program in Visual Studio, the whole text "Username"
  is selected so when i start typing it will be ok, since it overwrites
  it.
- But when i launch the exe directly, the username is not selected, the
  cursor pointer is before the first letter, so if i type "Anything" it
  will be "AnythingUsername".

Picture what i'm talking about:
[image]

It must be some bug,
Is it possible to make the "Username" default text selected when i launch the exe directly?

Comment: When you run your app, you actually run the executable created in `\bin\Debug` or `\bin\Release`. It's something else. -- Anyway, in `Form.Shown` or `OnShown()` add `this.ActiveControl = yourTextBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the text form inside the text box when it loads

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine. It was werid that when the visual studio opens the exe it's selected and when i open the exe directly it's not, but now both times selected. Thank you again.